# SCSS: Can I only @include in response to a successful @media?

Tags: sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

With SCSS files, I am attempting to make a responsive layout by setting variables in response to an @media query.

I currently have two @media queries, and I was hoping that only one of them would proceed to call the @mixin, with the map defined for the specific situation: mobile or desktop.

My code is :

```
$page-header-height : 45px;   // some dummy defaults
$page-subheader-height: 45px;
$page-footer-height : 50px;

$mobile-varmap : (
    "page-header-height" : 50px,
    "page-subheader-height": 50px
);

$desktop-varmap : (
    "page-header-height" : 90px,
    "page-subheader-height": 120px
);

@mixin setvariables($map) {
    $page-header-height: map-get($map, "page-header-height") !global;
    $page-subheader-height: map-get($map, "page-subheader-height") !global;
    $page-footer-height: 50px;
}
$screen-size-mobile: 360px;
$screen-size-tablet: 600px;

@media screen and (min-width:$screen-size-mobile) {
    body {
        @include setvariables($mobile-varmap);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:$screen-size-tablet) {
    body {
        @include setvariables($desktop-varmap);
    }
}

div.page-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'page-header''page-subheader''page-content''page-footer';
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: $page-header-height $page-subheader-height 1fr $page-footer-height;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 55px); // TODO: use variables to calc these
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow: none;
}
```

I had expected that this would lead to $page-header-height, etc, being set according to the matching @media query, but the result is that whichever @media query appears last in the code, determines the values which are produced.

What would I need to do in order to call `setvariables()`  with the `varmap` that corresponds to the screen size?

NB: I only added the `body` tags to the @media queries in response to viewing some examples - I'm not sure that they are correcty used or indeed necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but as i understand it, you expect the variables set via `@include setvariables($desktop-varmap);` to dynamically respond to device width... which will not happen because the two blocks with the media query do not render anything, the variables are just changed at compile time.

A possible way to build what you want is to have only one configuration map which then could be iterated over like

```scss
@mixin setvariables($map) {
    $page-header-height: map-get($map, "page-header-height") !global;
    $page-subheader-height: map-get($map, "page-subheader-height") !global;
    $page-footer-height: 50px !global;
}

$responsive-vars: (
    mobile: (
        min-width: 360px,
        page-header-height: 50px,
        page-subheader-height: 50px
    ),
    desktop: (
        min-width: 600px,
        page-header-height: 90px,
        page-subheader-height: 120px
    )
);

@each $alias, $map in $responsive-vars {
    @media screen and (min-width: map-get($map, 'min-width')) {
        @include setvariables($map);
        
        div.page-wrapper {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-areas: 'page-header''page-subheader''page-content''page-footer';
            grid-template-columns: auto;
            grid-template-rows: $page-header-height $page-subheader-height 1fr $page-footer-height;
            max-height: calc(100vh - 55px); // TODO: use variables to calc these
            min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
            overflow: none;
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not the most practical approach, since mostly you want to tweak only some values and have other declarations for all devices. Instead, i'd recommend to drop the `setvariables()` mixin entirely and access the maps directly like:

```scss
// https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/#deep-get
@function map-deep-get($map, $keys...) {
    @each $key in $keys {
        $map: map-get($map, $key);
    }
    @return $map;
}

$responsive-vars: (
    mobile: (
        min-width: 360px,
        page-header-height: 50px,
        page-subheader-height: 50px
    ),
    desktop: (
        min-width: 600px,
        page-header-height: 90px,
        page-subheader-height: 120px
    )
);

div.page-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'page-header''page-subheader''page-content''page-footer';
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 55px); // TODO: use variables to calc these
    min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow: none;
    
    @media screen and (min-width: map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'mobile', 'min-width')) {
        grid-template-rows: 
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'mobile', 'page-header-height')
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'mobile', 'page-subheader-height')
            1fr
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'mobile', 'page-footer-height');
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'desktop', 'min-width')) {
        grid-template-rows: 
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'desktop', 'page-header-height')
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'desktop', 'page-subheader-height')
            1fr
            map-deep-get($responsive-vars, 'desktop', 'page-footer-height');
    }
}
```

This may look like a lot of code at first glance, but it renders far less css.

Comment: That has assisted me greatly in my understanding of what the problem with my approach was.  Thanks for the guidance, Hans.